# Keyword (OR, AND) search in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene in my portal (J2EE based) for indexing and search services.

The problem is about the keywords of Lucene. When you use one of them in the search query, you'll get an error.

For example:

```
searchTerms = "ik OR jij"
```

This works fine, because it will search for `"ik"` or `"jij"`

```
searchTerms = "ik AND jij"
```

This works fine, it searches for `"ik"` and `"jij"`

But when you search:

```
searchTerms = "OR"
searchTerms = "AND"
searchTerms = "ik OR"
searchTerms = "OR ik"
```

Etc., it will fail with an error:

```
Component Name: STSE_RESULTS  Class: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException  Message: Cannot parse 'OR jij': Encountered "OR" at line 1, column 0. 
Was expecting one of: 
...
```

It makes sense, because these words are keywords for Lucene are probably reserved and will act as keywords.

In Dutch, the word "OR" is important because it has a meaning for "Ondernemings Raad". It is used in many texts, and it needs to be found. For example "or" does work, but does not return texts matching the term "OR". How can I make it searchable?

How can I escape the keyword "or"? Or How can I tell Lucene to treat "or" as a search term NOT as a keyword.

Comment: which version of Lucene?  AFAIk,Boolean query works for me with BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD | MUST | MUSTNOT( OR | AND | NOT) resp.

Comment: does the search work in Luke ==> http://www.getopt.org/luke/

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you have tried putting the "OR" into double quotes?

If that doesn't work I think you might have to go so far as to change the Lucene source and then recompile the whole thing, as the operator "OR" is buried deep inside the code. Actually, compiling probably isn't even enough: you'll have to change the  file QueryParser.jj in the source package that serves as input for JavaCC, then run JavaCC, then recompile the whole thing.

The good news, however, is that there's only one line to change:

`| <OR:        ("OR" | "||") >`

becomes

`| <OR:        ("||") >`

That way, you'll have only "||" as logical OR operator. There is a build.xml that also contains the invocation of JavaCC, but you have to download [that tool](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) yourself. I can't try it myself right now, I'm afraid.

This is perhaps a good question for the Lucene developer mailing list, but please let us know if you do that and they come up with a simpler solution ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**OR**, **NOT** and **AND** are reserved keywords. I solved this problem just 2 days ago by lower-casing those 3 words in the user's search term before feeding it into the lucene query parser. Note that if you search and replace for these keywords make sure you use word boundaries (\b) so you don't end up changing words such as ANDROID and ORDER.

I then let the user specify **NOT** and **AND** by using - and +, just like Google does.

Answer (score 3):

Escaping OR and AND with double quotes works for me. So try with a Java string like

`String query = "field:\"AND\"";`

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question many times! =[

please look at these suggestions

How is your index stored?

Document containing  Fields stored can be stored as

1)Stored  2)Tokenized 3)Indexed 4)Vector

it can make a significant **[difference](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#head-50101e914b87f70d9c2cd0dfafef07621d26bfe6)**

please use **[Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/)**, it can tell you how your indexes are stored(actually)

Luke is a *must* have if you are working with lucene, as it gives you a real idea of how indexes are stored,it also offers search, try it let us know with your update!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something wrong when you're building the query.  I'll second Narayan's suggestion on getting Luke (as posted in the comments) and try running your queries with that.  It has been a little while since I used Lucene, but I don't remember ever having issues with OR and AND.

Other than that, you can try escaping the input strings using QueryParser.escape(userQuery)

[More On Escaping](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t86124.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can escape the "OR" when it's a search term, or write your own query parser for a different syntax. Lucene offers an extensive query API in addition to the parser, with which you support your own query syntax quite easily.