# Hibernate search beginner question

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search

I am just beginning with Hibernate Search. The code I am using to do the search is taken from the reference guide:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
    Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();

try
{
    transaction.begin();

    // create native Lucene query using the query DSL
    // alternatively you can write the Lucene query using the
    // Lucene query parser or the Lucene programmatic API.
    // The Hibernate Search DSL is recommended though
    SearchFactory sf = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory();
    QueryBuilder qb = sf
      .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Item.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
      .keyword()
      .onFields("title", "description")
      .matching(queryString)
      .createQuery();

    // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
    javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = 
    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, Item.class);

    // execute search
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Item> result = persistenceQuery.getResultList();

    transaction.commit();

    return result;
}
catch (RuntimeException e) 
{
    transaction.rollback();
    throw e;
}
```

I notice that the query terms are interpreted as terms in a disjunction(OR). I would like them to be interpreted as conjunction terms instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Query parser, then you could do it this way:

```
    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("all", new GermanSnowBallAnalyzer());
    queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.AND_OPERATOR);
    Query luceneQuery = queryParser.parse(QueryParser.escape(keyword));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using the Hibernate Search query DSL you could write your query as:

```
Query luceneQuery = qb
    .bool()
      .must( qb.keyword().onField("title").matching(queryString).createQuery() )
      .must( qb.keyword().onField("description").matching(queryString).createQuery() )
    .createQuery();
```

Note that the query string is not parsed via the Lucene query parser. It has to contain the terms as you want to search for them (analyzers will be applied!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Hibernate Search too much, but I guess 'keyword()' will prepare a search based on tags, that are generally OR-based.

There are similar questions in the two links above, hope it helps:
[Keyword (OR, AND) search in Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311304/keyword-or-and-search-in-lucene)
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1008903&start=0